# Set static IP in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, network-interface, raspbian

I set up the above file as below to get static IP on my wireless interface:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    wpa-ssid "essid"
    wpa-psk "password"
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

I even rebooted the PC. However, the wireless interface is still getting an address via dhcp in the range >192.168.0.100. Is there some error in the above syntax please?

Comment: check if the dhcpcd is runing on your raspbian `systemctl status dhcpcd.service`

Answer (score 0):

stop the dhcp client daemon otherwise it will run, ask for an ip address and override your static config